Unresolved reference 'option' error in Android Studio when building a Protobuffer/Kotlin app
I'm using Android Studio Koala Feature Drop | 2024.1.2 Patch 1.
I'm trying to get a simple Protobuffer app up and running and while there is a fair amount of sample code around on how to get this implemented and I not managed (yet) to achieve this.
When I try and sync the project I get the following error.
Unresolved reference: option
The (relevant) cradle snippets to generate the protobuf code are as follows
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.3"

}

  sourceSets{
        getByName("main") {
            kotlin {
                srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
            }
            proto {
                srcDir("src/main/proto")
            }
        }


dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation (libs.protobuf.kotlin.lite)

protobuf{
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.22.2"
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach { task ->
            task.builtins {
                kotlin{
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


The error happens on the line
option("lite")

despite the IDE 'suggesting' the line as it is when I start the line 'kotlin{}'...
I've tried to follow these posts and any posts that are referred
Ref1
Ref2

Thanks to this approach I can now generate kotlin code from a .proto file
Following are the steps I followed

In the project build.gradle add the following to the plugins{} block
id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4" apply false


the plugins{} block should look similar to this
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4" apply false}


In the app build.grade I made the following changes

2.a) add the following at the beginning of the file
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

2.b) add the following to the plugins{} block
 id("com.google.protobuf")

The block should look something like this
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
id("com.google.protobuf")}

2.c) add the following to the dependencies{} block
implementation ("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin-lite:3.20.1")

2.d) add the following at the bottom of the file
protobuf {
  protoc {
      artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.21.2"
}
plugins {
    id("java") {
        artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.47.0"
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all().forEach {
        it.plugins {
            id("java") {
                option("lite")
            }
        }
        it.builtins {
            id("kotlin") {
                option("lite")
            }
        }
    }
}

2.e) Sync your project
2.f) Create the proto folder under ..../yourapp/app/src/main
2.g) Create the .proto file in ..../yourapp/app/src/main/proto
2.h) run make
2.i) The (generated) java folder should now have the kotlin code for protobuffer.
